# A proof of Taylor's Peano Remainder using little o notation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, numerical-methods, asymptotics

I have two questions relating to a proof I found of the Peano remainder form: $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_{0})}{k!}(x-x_{0})^{k}+\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|^{n}\right)$. Keep in mind that the little o notation here is that if $f \in \mathrm{o}(t)$ then: $ \lim_{\substack{t\rightarrow0\\ t\neq0} }\frac{f(t)}{t}=0$

I am not interested in general proofs of Peano's remainder form, but particularly in how the little o notation is manipulated. So this is more of a little o notation question than a Taylor's theorem proof question.

---

This [linked proof](https://mth49601spring2010.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/supplement-to-lecture-6-taylors-theorem-big-oh-and-little-oh/) begins using the integral form of the remainder and the assumption that $f \in C^n$, so the proof has an extra assumption compared to the normal Peano remainder proofs, which usually only assume $n$ times differentiability (so $f^{(n)}$ is not necessarily continuous).

My first issue is with the proof itself, which says that
\begin{aligned}\frac{(x-x_{0})^{n}}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{1}\left[f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))-f^{(n)}(x_{0})\right](1-t)^{n-1}dt.\end{aligned} 
can be simplified to $\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|^{n}\right)$.

The last line says that since $f^{(n)}$ is assumed continuous, we have that $\left[f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))-f^{(n)}(x_{0})\right] \in \mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|\right)$. I am trying to show that this is true, but can't seem to justify it.

I think that continuity is necessary so that the limit as $x \rightarrow x_0$ of $f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))$ is $f^{(n)}(x_{0})$ and so the $\left[f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))-f^{(n)}(x_{0})\right]$ term goes to $0$. But I am not sure how this implies that $\left[f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))-f^{(n)}(x_{0})\right]$ goes to $0$ faster than $(|x-x_{0}|)$, since we have no details about $f^{(n)}$. I am thinking it could be since $t \in [0,1]$ and so for a given increment $x - x_0$, $f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))$ is closer to $f^{(n)}(x_{0})$ than $f^{(n)}(x_{0}+(x-x_{0}))$ otherwise would have been, but I'm unsure if this is valid reasoning. It also seems more like a 'big O' case than 'little o'.

In addition, I am wondering how 
\begin{aligned}\frac{(x-x_{0})^{n}}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|\right)\right](1-t)^{n-1}dt.\end{aligned} 
is simplified to $\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|^{n}\right)$, since there is an $(x-x_{0})^{n}$ multiplied by $\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|\right)$, which I think should be $\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|^{n+1}\right)$ and not $\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|^{n}\right)$ as the remainder should appear as.

So those are my main questions, and my confusion mostly pertains to the little o notation and it's manipulations. I know there are other proofs for Taylor's theorem but wanted to understand this notation a bit better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This theorem is already discussed in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809293/72031).

Comment: My question is less about the theorem and more about how the little o notation is used and how it works

Comment: Assume that we are dealing with some limiting behavior of functions of $x$ as $x\to a$ ($a$ can be $\pm\infty$ also). The little-o notation assumes that this information is provided implicitly or via context. Then $f(x) = o(g(x)) $ is just another way of saying that $f(x) /g(x) \to 0$. If someone writes $f(x) =g(x) +o(h(x)) $ then it means $f(x) - g(x) =o(h(x)) $ and this further means that $(f(x) - g(x)) /h(x) \to 0$. Thus every statement which contains this little-o is in reality a statement about limits.

Comment: The proof of Taylor's theorem with Peano's form of remainder is not done via integrals as that approach requires more hypotheses than actually needed. Moreover integrating things like $o(f(x)) $ are tricky. Thus for example if $f(x) =o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$ then $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt=o(x^4)$ but this is mainly a consequence of L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. Do you have any idea why if $f^{(n)}$ is continuous then the author implies $\left[f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))-f^{(n)}(x_{0})\right] \in \mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|\right)$, (for $t \in [0,1]$). I can't seem to show this.

My other issue was with \begin{aligned}\frac{(x-x_{0})^{n}}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|\right)\right](1-t)^{n-1}dt.\end{aligned} since it is said to be $\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|^{n}\right)$, but looks $\mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|^{n+1}\right)$ to me

Comment: Well the difference $f^{(n)} (a+t(x-a)) +f^{(n)} (a) $ is less than $\epsilon$ (ie it is $o(1)$) via continuity and hence the overall expression is less than $\epsilon(x-a) ^n/n! $. This means it is $o((x-a) ^n) $.

Comment: Okay I think the second issue is resolved then, although the author's work isn't very clear. Did you think of a way to show $\left[f^{(n)}(x_{0}+t(x-x_{0}))-f^{(n)}(x_{0})\right] \in \mathrm{o}\left(|x-x_{0}|\right)$? I tried to but can only get the result if the difference is $< \epsilon * |x - x_0|$ which I can't prove

Comment: Read my last comment again which uses $a$ instead of $x_0$ to save typing effort. The analysis by author here is wrong.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was wrong. Whatever you wrote makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You should leave a comment on the author's blog so that the author fixes this error. This will save many other readers from the confusion you faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already given some details in the comments but it appears that it is better to combine them to form an answer.

---

Taylor's theorem with Peano's form of remainder uses minimal assumptions of the function and then gives a simple estimate for the remainder. A proof is given here in another answer. I have myself discussed this topic in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809293/72031).

The proof provided in the question uses integrals and thus assumes more than what is needed. In particular the assumption here is that n-th derivative $f^{(n)} $ is continuous in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Also the proof contains a subtle error. The author writes $$f^{(n)} (x_{0}+t(x-x_0))-f^{(n)}(x_0)=o(|x-x_0|)$$ This should be replaced by $$f^{(n)} (x_{0}+t(x-x_0))-f^{(n)}(x_0)=o(1)$$ (this is an immediate consequence of continuity of $f^{(n)} $) and then the later part of the proof works fine.

I don't know if the mistake by author is a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Let's state more or less the statement you want to prove:

*Suppose $f$ is $n-1$--times differentiable in a neighborhood of a point $a$, and that $f^{(n-1)}$ is differentiable at $a$, then
$$r(x):=f(x)-\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k = o\big((x-a)^n\big)$$*

-Notice that no continuity on the $n$--th derivative is assumed and that only two things are required: (1) all derivatives up to order $n-1$ in an interval around $a$ exists, (2) the $n$--th derivative at $a$ exists.

**Proof:**
Set $g(x)=(x-a)^n$. Notice that

- $r$ and $g$ are $n$--times differentiable at $a$,
- $r^{(k)}(a)=0$ for all $0\leq k\leq n$,
- and $g^{(k)}(x)\neq0$ for all $x\neq a$ and $0\leq k\leq n$.

Recall the Cauchy mean value theorem for two differentiable functions that states that for any differentiable functions $F$ and $G$ in an interval $[\alpha,\beta]$, there is a point $\alpha<\xi<\beta$ such that
$$ G'(\xi)(F(\beta)-F(\alpha))=F'(\xi)(G(\beta)-G(\alpha))$$

Using this theorem repeatedly, we obtain that there are points $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n$ such that $\xi_k$ is between $a$ and $\xi_{k-1}$ ( define $\xi_0=x$), such that
\begin{aligned}
\frac{r(x)}{g(x)}&=\frac{r(x)-r(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{r'(\xi_1)}{g'(\xi_1)}=\frac{r'(\xi_1)-r'(a)}{g'(\xi_1)-g'(a)}
=\frac{r''(\xi_2)}{g''(\xi_2)}\\
&=\ldots=\frac{r^{(n-1)}(\xi_{n-1})}{g^{(n-1)}(\xi_{n-1})}=\frac{r^{(n-1)}(\xi_{n-1}) - r^{(n-1)}(a)}{g^{(n-1)}(\xi_{n-1})-g^{(n-1)}(a)}=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{r^{(n-1)}(\xi_{n-1})-r^{(n-1)}(a)}{\xi_{n-1}-a}
\end{aligned}
The $\xi$'s depend on $x$ and
\begin{aligned}
 a<\xi_{n-1}<\ldots<\xi_1<x,&\qquad\text{if}\quad a<x\\
x<\xi_1<\ldots<\xi_{n-1}<a, &\qquad\text{if}\quad x<a
\end{aligned}
Thus, as $x\rightarrow a$, so do all $\xi_k\rightarrow a$, and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{r(x)}{(x-a)^n}=\lim_{\xi_{n-1}\rightarrow a}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{r^{(n-1)}(\xi_{n-1})-r^{(n-1)}(a)}{\xi_{n-1}-a}=\frac{1}{n!}r^{(n)}(a)=0$$
where the last limit holds by the fact that $f^{(n-1)}$, and hence $r^{(n-1)}$, is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: Nice proof directly using Cauchy Mean Value Theorem instead of its infamous consequence L'Hospital's Rule. +1

Comment: It is in a sense the way one typically proves L'Hospital rule.