# Mean-Value Theorem: applications

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, cauchy-principal-value

**The Generalized Mean-Value Theorem** or Cauchy's theorem or of the finite increments theorem says:

> If functions $f$ and $g$ are both continuous on $[a,b]\subset\Bbb R$ and differentiable on $]a,b[\subset\Bbb R$, and if
> $g'(x)\neq 0$ for every $x\in]a,b[$, then there exists a number $\xi$ in $]a,b[$ such that

> $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(a)-g(b)}=\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}$$

If $g(x)=x$ I found the Lagrange's theorem.

[image: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Proof_of_Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem]

This theorem says that it is also possible that there are multiple tangents parallel to the secant (see the image).

- *What is the importance to have multiple tangents parallel to the secant in a specific exercise*?

This theorem is now almost omitted from Italian school books: there is only the enunciate and few exercises.

I have taken an screenshot of a English book,

[image]

and I see many exercises of Lagrange's theorem to justify inequalities.

- *At this point I ask to all users on Math.SE a curiosity: what could be good uses for the generalized mean-value theorem or of Cauchy*?

Comment: You can use that result to justify L'Hostpital rule. You can also use the result to get Taylor's polynomial (with some additional assumptions)

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes of course. There is into the link of the 1st image to justify de l'Hopital rule. Every answer is welcome for the Taylor's polynomial.

Comment: For Taylor's polynomial  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3406636/121671)  is a link that uses the GMVT