# Taylor's Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So, I'm reading Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*, and he has a theorem about Taylor polynomials that I can't find in many other places. It is:

Assume that f : (a, b) → R is rth order differentiable at x. Then:
(a) The rth order Taylor Polynomial P approximates f to order r at x in the sense that the Taylor remainder $R(h)=f(x+h)−P(h)$ is rth order flat at h = 0; i.e., $\frac{R(h)}{h^r}$ → 0 as h → 0.

(b) The Taylor polynomial is the only polynomial of degree ≤ r with this approximation property

To prove this, Pugh says:

(a) The first r derivatives of R(h) exist and equal 0 at h = 0. If h > 0 then
repeated applications of the Mean Value Theorem give
$R(h)=R'(θ_1)h =R''(θ_2)θ_1h=R^{(r−1)}(θ_{r−1})(θ_{r−2})...θ_1h$, where $0<θ_{r−1}<...< θ_1< h$. Thus $|\frac{R(h)}{h^r}|=|\frac{R^{(r−1)}(θ_{r−1})(θ_{r−2})...θ_1h}{h^r}|\leq |\frac{R^{(r−1)}(θ_{r−1})−0}{θ_{r−1}}|$, which goes to 0 as h goes to 0.
If $h<0$ the same is true with $h<θ_1<...<θ_{r−1}<0$.

(b) If $Q(h)$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq r$, $Q \neq P$, then $Q−P$ isn't rth-order
flat at h = 0, so $f(x+h)−Q(h)$ cannot be rth-order flat either.

Here are my questions:

I understand the upper bound on $|\frac{R(h)}{h^r}|$, but why does that go to zero as h goes to zero? The best I can do is see that $R^{(r-1)}$ is differentiable and thus continuous, so L'Hopital's rule applies, but where do I go from here?

I understand why $Q-P$ isn't rth-order flat, but how does that have any bearing on $f(x+h)-Q(h)$ being rth-order flat?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you for your informative comment on the prior post; I now see that Pugh was implicitly using the limit definition of the derivative. My second question about why the rth order Taylor polynomial is the only polynomial of degree less than or equal to r such that the remainder is rth-order flat still stands, though.

Comment: That has been answered in MSE already. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4438339/121671) for example

Comment: This version of the Taylor theorem is covered in the Wikipedia article

Comment: FYI, these conceptual characterizations of the Taylor polynomials are also emphasized in Spivak’s *Calculus*.

Comment: @TedShifrin: These characterizations were common in soviet books from the 50's too. Piskunov's Caculus was translated into English by Mir Nauka (now defunct unfortunately).

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you so much!

Comment: @RHyp: You're welcome... if any of the posting I linked helped you, I would appreciate your upvote. If not, it is also fine...