# Proving that a Polynomial Equals the $m$-th Degree Taylor Polynomial of a Function based on a Given Limit Expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f \in C^{m+1}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ be a function, and let $P: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $m$. Suppose $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $$\lim_{{x \to a}} \frac{\left| f(x) - P(x) \right|}{\|x - a\|^m} = 0 $$
Show that $P$ must necessarily be equal to the $m$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$.

My attempt: To show that $P$ must be equal to the $m$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$, we'll utilize the Taylor's theorem with the remainder term in the Lagrange form. The theorem states that for a function $f$ which is $(m+1)$ times differentiable on an interval containing $a$ and a point $x$ in that interval, there exists a point $c$ between $a$ and $x$ such that:
$$\begin{split}f(x) &= f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \frac{2!}{2!}f''(a)(x - a)^2 + \ldots + \frac{m!}{m!}f^{(m)}(a)(x - a)^m\\
&\quad+ \frac{(m+1)!}{(m+1)!}f^{(m+1)}(c)(x - a)^{m+1}\end{split}$$ In this case, we want to show that $P(x)$, which is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $m$, agrees with the Taylor polynomial of $f$ up to the $m$-th degree terms.

Is my way of thinking correct? How can I continue this proof?

Comment: Would this answer your question, or at least would it help you? [Proving that T is the Taylor Polynomial of f of degree n.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4438339)

Comment: it's not really clear how can I use this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $Q$ your $m$-degree Taylor polynomial of $f$, you get
$$(f-Q) (x-a) = o (|x-a|^m)$$
Just use the difference:
$$\frac{|(P-f +f -Q)(x-a)|}{|x-a|^m} \leqslant \frac{|(P-f)(x-a)|}{|x-a|^m} + \frac{|(f -Q)(x-a)|}{|x-a|^m} \rightarrow 0$$
With that you get $R=(P-Q)(X-a)$ a polynomial of degree $\leqslant m$ that verifies
$$\frac{R(x)}{x^m} \rightarrow 0$$
for $x \rightarrow 0$.
Which means $R=0$ hence $P=Q$.

What you did is express the Taylor polynomial but the goal is not to prove existence but unicity; your way of thinking is good though but maybe overkill?

Comment: $(f-Q)(x-a) = o(|x-a|^m)$ what do you mean by $o$?

Comment: If $g$ does not vanish near a point $a$ (but may vanish in $a$, $f = o_a (g)$ if $f/g \rightarrow 0$ in $a$

Comment: Note that the proof will strongly depend on your definition of the Taylor polynomials

Comment: I must add a warning, you used multidimensional variables, the Taylor polynomials don’t exist for them, it is much more complicated. You could define it with an alternative “polynomial” on the bar resolution $\bigcup E^{\otimes n}$ with product defined by distributivity on the tensor product… But you better stick to the one dimensional thing